# Dungeon Siege 2 has no sound during cinematics

Tags: pc, technical-issues, dungeon-siege-2

I'm trying to run my Dungeon Siege 2 game on Windows 7 64-bit and it has no sound during cinematics, but sound works during gameplay.

What could the cause be and how could I fix it?

Comment: My first assumption would be win 7 64-bit. Try running it in xp compatibility mode and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have installed DirectX 9?

It may have something to do with a video playback problem blocking the sound. Try to fine tune you video setting with the program "DSVideoConfig.exe" in your Dungeon Siege 2 folder.

See also: http://deathmarine.com/dungeon-siege-and-windows-7-x64/